# Trouble formatting date and time values in SQL Server in a T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure where part of it I want to set 2 variables, 1 for the current time and the other for the current date. I need them in `hhmm` format for the time and `yyyyMMdd` format for the date.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @d AS DATETIME 
    DECLARE @t as TIME

    SET @d = GETDATE()
    SET @t  = SYSDATETIME()
```

But everything I've tried to use to change the format of those 2 variables does not help me out. The only examples I've found online is for formatting values in regular queries.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as what I should do to get these values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also: why are you using the deprecated `GETDATE()` function to get the current date? You should really also use `SYSDATETIME()` for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2012+ you can use Format()

**Example**

```
DECLARE @d as varchar(8) = format(GetDate(),'yyyyMMdd')
DECLARE @t as varchar(4) = format(SYSDATETIME(),'HHmm')   -- use hh for 12 hour time

Select @d,@t
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
20180511            1738
```

> **For 2005**

```
DECLARE @d as varchar(8) = convert(varchar(10),GetDate(),112)
DECLARE @t as varchar(8) = replace(left(convert(varchar(25),SYSDATETIME(),108),5),':','')
```

Comment: Just beat me too it, alternatively you can use : CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),112)  for date and REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), SYSDATETIME(),108),':','') for time

Comment: @HolmesIV Post alternative.  OP may not be on 2012+

Comment: but he might be :) thats why i put it in comment, not trying to steal pts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but unfortunately we're running 2005. Any other suggestions? I'll try the other suggestion actually......

Comment: @BrendonDavies See Update

Comment: @Holmes IV thanks for the alternate reply. Kind of ugly, but it works and that is what is most important.

Comment: @HolmesIV  ++ because you didn't post alternative which OP needed